# Why do we see the sun's light color different from the moon's light color?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, sun, moon

Why do we see the color of the sun's light as red or orange, while we see the moon's light as white, although it's reflected from the sun?

Comment: The sun seems pretty white most of the time. The only time it doesn't look white is in the morning or evening, when it looks red because of atmospheric effects.

Comment: The moon also looks yellow or even reddish when low on the horizon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The light of the moon is a reflected light, and thus displays the [type of surface](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/smith/Astro150/Tutorials/Spectra/) on the moon in its spectral composition.

On the other hand the red orange of sun is seen through clouds or low in the horizon from secondary interactions. When overhead it is yellow and if behind clouds sometimes  white . Part of the difference in the colors we perceive is also due to the much smaller amplitude of the light of the moon.We can look at the moon directly, not at the sun.